# What exactly happens to the melting point of a substance (except water) due to the presence of impurities?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

According to my idea, the impurities will absorb a certain amount of heat too, due to the which the melting point of the actual substance should increase, because, I think, now the actual substance will require more heat from the source, as some of the heat energy is consumed by the impurities. Am I right or, if not, why?

Comment: Heat capacity and melting point are not related.

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean, but in that case, pls can you explain me the actual phenomenon occuring here, I can't understand what my book syas quite clearly, if you could help, I would be highly thankful

Comment: Water becomes a solid when intermolecular forces become strong. Dipole dipole interactions in polar molecules become weaker in the presence of ions as they can easily interact with the ions instead thus the melting point drops

Comment: @AniketRoy What does your book say, and which part is confusing to you?

Comment: My book is very brief in that matter, it simply says that, The melting point of a substance decreases with the presence of impurities in it. For example, the melting point of ice decreases from 0°C to -22°C on mixing salt with it in proper proportion. Thia is what my book says, and I want to know, the exact reason behind all this phenomenon, Pls describe, if you can

Answer (score 0):

> My book is very brief in that matter, it simply says that, The melting point of a substance decreases with the presence of impurities in it. For example, the melting point of ice decreases from 0°C to -22°C on mixing salt with it in proper proportion.

Unfortunately, you have a poor book. Keep looking for other resources (textbooks, ideally) to fill in your knowledge.

What the book likely means is that the **freezing** point of a liquid decreases with a **small** addition of **nonvolatile** impurities **that are excluded from the solid**. Let's address each of these points.

Water is often used as example, but the behavior is general. Let's instead use the example of liquid metal containing a small amount of impurities. Let's further assume that the impurities (which move around with no problem in the liquid) don't fit well into the solid metal crystal. In other words, they are *[segregated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segregation_(materials_science))* from the solid; freezing some of the liquid results in a less pure liquid and a more pure solid (in terms of dissolved impurities). (This concept is applied in so-called [zone refining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_melting)).

The melting/freezing point typically corresponds to the temperature where we see equal rates of (1) molecules in the liquid attaching to the solid and (2) molecules attached to the solid entering the liquid.

But when impurities exist, the concentration of solute—the metal host material—is less than one, which reduces any associated melting or freezing rate. Put another way, with impurity segregation, there's less metal in the liquid than in the solid, and so the rates become imbalanced such that less freezing occurs. This favors the liquid phase, and so the [freezing point is lowered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression).

Specifying the **freezing** point (as opposed to the melting point) is important for pedagogical purposes here because if the solid contains impurities and is melting, the effect may not occur—the impurities exist in both the solid and the newly formed liquid to an unknown degree, and it's not clear how much segregation occurs. ([Melting point depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting-point_depression) also refers to a separate phenomenon.) Thus, although you can generally take the melting and freezing points as the same in this point in your learning, the latter is the more appropriate term here.)

**Small** is an important qualifier because as the degree of impurity increases, the phase behavior begins to be governed by the solute, not the solvent. The technical term for the small-impurity behavior is [colligative behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colligative_properties).

The impurity must be both **nonvolatile** and be **excluded from the solid** to some degree so that it both stays in the liquid (as opposed to evaporating away) and is segregated somewhat from the solid. It's only in this case that we can reliably predict colligative [freezing point depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression).

> According to my idea, the impurities will absorb a certain amount of heat too, due to the which the melting point of the actual substance should increase, because, I think, now the actual substance will require more heat from the source, as some of the heat energy is consumed by the impurities.

A problem with this reasoning is that there less "actual substance" to be heated if it's impure. If this factor is incorporated, you can actually predict the correct answer: if the solid is purer and the liquid is less pure, then the freezing temperature should drop. The problem with your book is that it confuses where nonvolatile impurities tend to collect: the liquid phase (instead, by referring to an impure substance that's melting, it seems to imply that the impurities matter only in the solid phase). Nobody mixes salt thoroughly into solid ice; they put salt in contact with solid ice so that the salt easily mixes with any liquid water, causing the liquid water to become the favored phase and consequently to accumulate.

Does this all make sense?

Comment: Really appreciated all the help, thanks for sparing your time, I will read your answer thoroughly and let you know